# How to append new data to JTextArea in thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets, settext

My code:

```
public class ClientStarter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ClientGUI();                            
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My code:

```
public class ClientGUI {
    ClientMainForm mainForm;
    Client client;

    public ClientGUI() {
        mainForm = new ClientMainForm();
        client = new Client(Constants.HOST_NAME, Constants.PORT, mainForm);     
    }   
}
```

Client:

```
public class Client {
    protected Socket client;
    protected BufferedReader in;
    ClientMainForm mainForm;    

    public Client(String hostName, int ip, ClientMainForm mainForm) {
        try {
            this.client = new Socket(hostName, ip);
            this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    this.client.getInputStream()));
            this.mainForm = mainForm;
            String buffer = null;
            while ((buffer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                this.mainForm.appendTextMsg(buffer);                
                this.mainForm.getTextArea().setText(buffer);

                System.out.println(buffer);
            }               
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

new client form created but

```
 this.mainForm.appendTextMsg(buffer);               
    this.mainForm.getTextArea().setText(buffer);
```

in Client class loop do nothing when `System.out.println(buffer);` works fine and pops up in console.How dynamically add that info to the text area with append or set text methods?

Comment: You're blocking the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Run the loop in a background thread, and use `invokeLater()` only for the GUI updates.

Comment: can you sketch some code in your answer?I will try to apply it

Comment: You could use the text area's variable name, which is an object, to call the .append(String message) to append data to a text file. e.g. if my text area's variable name is txta1 and I want to append "Hello world" to it, the code would be: txta1.append("Hello world");  . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
class BackgroundThread implements Runnable {

   @Override
   public void run() {

      // the Swing call below must be queued onto the Swing event thread
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run() {
            // OK To make Swing method calls here
            //append JTextArea here
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I manually add new client so main method needed.I don't understand how to use invokeLater

Comment: What is your idea ? Do you want to append from multiple `JFrame` s ?

Comment: if use java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { no need to import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

Comment: when should I use invokeLater method?In which cases?It is normally works with simple threads insted of invokeLater

Comment: When you want to `update` or make some modifications on `Swing components` from a custom thread you will need `SwingUtilities` . Otherwise the modifications won't be visible.